# How to recover a deleted /usr partition?

Tags: partitioning, xubuntu

Accidently I formated my /usr partition of my Kubuntu in my Windows XP systems.

Is there any way to revover the /usr partition?

Comment: You could try your testdisk from your Live cd. :)

Comment: Testdisk indeed. But `/usr/` probably does not have any user content so as a last resort you could do a re-install without formatting/ Ofcouse you make a backup 1st before doing that ;)

Comment: @mikewhatever. Once in a while, my /usr directory lived in my / partition, and my / partition had a btrfs file system. Through LiveCD I can see the snapshot of my / partition, and /usr is there. Can I recover my /usr partition from here?

Answer (score 0):

Not really.  As an exercise question in a job interview, maybe; as a practical thing, no - easiest thing to do is just back up any data you had and do a clean reinstall.  (And don't delete system32 - er, I mean /usr - again.)